# installing GoogleMaps module in python

Tags: python, python-module

I installed **GoogleMaps** module via `pip`

```
pip install GoogleMaps
```

above command installed module in `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages`

but when I try load it gives me following error

```
>>> from googlemaps import GoogleMaps  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>  
  File "googlemaps.py", line 1, in <module>  
    from googlemaps import GoogleMaps  
ImportError: cannot import name GoogleMaps
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Is Question is not clear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have a python file called `googlemaps.py`?

This is causing a circular import and is repeatedly trying to import `GoogleMaps` from itself.

Try renaming your file to something else and see if that fixes your problem.